# CSS Grid: Sticky Corners

Tags: html, css

I've got a grid and I want the left most column to remain in view and the top row to remain in view. To mimic the behaviour of freezing them in excel.

I can get them to work on their own but when I combine them the top left corner behaves weirdly. Is there an easy solution to this or am I going to have to use js to measure the dimensions and then create an absolute version of it over the top?

I'd be happy if it just behaved liked the top row or left most column but no matter what class I give the top left column it doesn't work correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/eL4ux1gd/4/

```
<style>
.rtable-container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.rtable {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
}


.rtable-columnheader {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.rtable-rowheader {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.rtable-cornerheader {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.rtable-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class='rtable-container'>
  <div class='rtable'>
    <div class='rtable-cornerheader'>
      Corner
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-columnheader'>
      Column Header
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-columnheader'>
      Column Header
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-rowheader'>
      Row Header
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-cell'>
      A Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-cell'>
      A Cell 2
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-rowheader'>
      Row Header
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-cell'>
      A Cell 3
    </div>
    <div class='rtable-cell'>
      A Cell 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply increase the z-index of the corner element. It's already sticky but hidden

Comment: Thank you so much! That would have taken me ages to work out